# How to get Rowspan Rows Values with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract the td values belonging a td rowspan.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Expenses</th>
        <th>Exp/ Divided</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">January</td>
        <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">February</td>
        <td rowspan="3">$400</td>
        <td>$150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$100</td>
        <tr></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I click on January for example I have to extract its divided expenses: $50, $50

if I click on February I have to extract its divided expenses: $150, $150, $100

Comment: to be honest with you, i am plsql programmer, and don´t know this code , I just start reading some books, but my team ask me to complete this task by using JavaScript, but I am getting there, not yet, for now I just can ask for some help and learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('.rowspan').on('click',function(){
        $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
        rowspan=$(this).attr('rowspan');
        index=$('tr').index($tr);
        tot=parseInt(index)+parseInt(rowspan);
        for(var i=index,len=tot;i<len;i++){
            console.log($('tr:eq('+i+') td:last').text());
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2Ly7/)

Comment: There's got to be a mini-library out there that "flattens" a table into a 2D list of text contents or element references that accounts for colspan and rowspan.

Answer (score -1):

With jquery you can simply select the objects like so:

```
$("td[rowspan='2']");
```

To get the containing values it would be:

```
$("td[rowspan='2']").text();
```

More on this:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: The question is asking how to select the td cells adjacent to a given cell with a rowspan, not how to select a cell with a rowspan attribute.

Comment: Quoting question: "I am trying to extract the td values belonging a td rowspan." My answer is a direct response to the question, please remove your downvote.